# Auto refreshing a database and connection with java

Tags: java, mysql

I am using Frame with card layout and a few panels.
In the first panel, there is a textField object that reads name and a button, which on clicking adds the name to the database table. In the second panel, there is a dropdown box which reads the vales from the database which was inserted from the previous panel.

My problem is that, the vales from the db are not added to the dropdown box in the 2nd panel.
This will only work when I close the program and run it again.

Is there a way to refresh the tables and db and the database connection, so that, I will be able to see the values in the dropdown box without having to restart the application ?

Comment: It seems like you did not commit your transaction, and it's only committed when you exit your program. Could you provide code to understand what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Just bind an event to the button to make your dropdown menu to refresh.